# Thoughts about memory footprint

Tags: android, performance, android-sqlite, memory-footprint

A very pertinent question (at least I think it is) came to me while developing an Android app.

**Example**

We are inserting 10000 rows on a db (at once).

```
db.beginTransaction();
try{
    for(Object toInsert: listOfObjects) {
         ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        //put the values on the object
        values.put(key, toInsert.getValue());
        db.insert(columnName, null, values);
    }
    db.setTransactionSuccessful();
} catch(Exception e) {
    //handle exception
} finally {
    db.endTransaction();
}
```

We are creating 10000 new ContentValue objects on the loop. And object creation is very expensive to the VM.
And if we modify this a little bit?

**Different Approach**

```
ContentValues values, hack = new ContentValues();
db.beginTransaction();
try{
    for(Object toInsert: listOfObjects) {
         values = hack;
        //put the values on the object
        values.put(key, toInsert.getValue());
        db.insert(columnName, null, values);
    }
    db.setTransactionSuccessful();
} catch(Exception e) {
    //handle exception
} finally {
    db.endTransaction();
}
```

In this second example, we are making a 'reset' to the value object, because that will be used in every single row.

And so, my question is: Am I doing this right? With the second approach I'm optimizing the process without leaving a big memory footprint? If not, why? Have you some suggestions/thoughts about this?

Answer (score 1):

You are doing it wrong with the two variables.

Consider the following case:
In first iteration, `values = new instance`, `hack = new instance`. OK.
after you do `values = hack`. `values` and `hack` both refer to the same memory location now. So there is no point in creating two variables.

You could simply do following:

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
db.beginTransaction();
try{
    for(Object toInsert: listOfObjects) {
        //put the values on the object
        values.put(key, toInsert.getValue());
        db.insert(columnName, null, values);
    }
    db.setTransactionSuccessful();
} catch(Exception e) {
    //handle exception
} finally {
    db.endTransaction();
}
```

Comment: And if we are inserting values with different keys on each loop? That will not work.. EDIT: But +1 for the memory address reference. I totally forgot that. :)

Comment: Yes, we will have problem in that case. The only way I see is to reset the keys of content values. :)

Comment: I think that it is a good way to go. But, it will be more fast than alocating a new object?